# Most efficient way to find whether all objects belong to the same group?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I have some objects each with an integer field group number. I want to find in the most efficient time whether all objects belong to the same group. Can this be done in less than O(n) time in C++ ?

Comment: Any constraints on in what container the objects are given (your example doesn't look like C++)?

Comment: The objects are sent in arrays of Node type. I can change that but I dont want to modify a lot of my code.What do you suggest ?

Comment: In that case you need to look at each element at least once to determine its group, so I think you cannot do better than O(N).

Comment: What container do you suggest ? Maybe I should use parallelism for this portion. All objects return their group number and I check if all are equal or not.Like MPI_reduce call. Can I do this in C++?  I am newbie so I dont know how.

Comment: Maybe you could restate your actual problem (the answer to your current question is just *No*).

Comment: I edited my code to remove the restriction on the function signature.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51166/discussion-between-benjamin-bannier-and-worker)

Comment: The answer stays the same. Parallelism only helps if the group is easily partitioned and big enough.

Comment: I have modified my question to remove O(1) restriction. Now I just want to do better than O(N)

Answer (score 2):

No, without doing some preprocessing outside of your function you cannot do this better than with O(N), e.g. in O(1).

To find out if all elements belong to the same group you will (at least in the worst case) need to look at all elements once to determine their group which makes this immediately O(N).

The simplest algorithm would look something like this (Python pseudocode):

```
def all_same_group(elements):
  group0 = elements[0].group  # group of first element

  # iterate over remaining elements
  for element in elements[1:]:
    if element.group != group0:
       return False  # element has different group, not all same
  return True        # we didn't return in the loop, so all same
```

Assuming only two groups this will in the best case (where the first and
second elements have different groups) perform in O(1). Assuming equal
probabilities of the two groups and random ordering of elements this will
require to check O(log(N)) elements. In the worst case it is still O(N) where
you need to check all elements.